Why my upload function is being called two times
I am just trying to built something like real time video recorder (not actually ),just trying to save video every few seconds in cloud.
I wrote some code in reactjs, here when my webcam mounts , I start camera & starts recording using mediaRecorder and want to stop recording when camera unmounts
my code :
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { axiosServerInstance } from "@/utils/api/instances";
import { serverRoutes } from "@/utils/api/routes";

const cloudinaryUploadUrl = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/-----/video/upload";

const WebCam = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const recordedChunksRef = useRef([]);
  const uploadIntervalRef = useRef(null);
  const [isUploading,setIsUploading]=useState(false)
  const isComponentMounted = useRef(true); 
  const proctorId = useSelector((state) => state?.assessment?.assessmentTestData?.report?.proctorId);

  const updateProctorVideoUrl = async (chunks) => {
    try {
     
        await axiosServerInstance.put(serverRoutes.submitVideoUrl, {
          proctorId,
          ...chunks,
        });
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating proctor:", error.response?.data || error.message);
    }
  };

  const uploadToCloudinary = async (blob) => {
    if (!isComponentMounted.current) return; 

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", blob);
    formData.append("upload_preset", "-----");

    try {
      const response = await fetch(cloudinaryUploadUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      await updateProctorVideoUrl({
        asset_id: data.asset_id,
        public_id: data.public_id,
        url: data.url,
        proctorId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading video:", error);
    }
  };

  const startCamera = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
      if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      }
      return stream;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error accessing camera:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const startRecording = (stream) => {
    recordedChunksRef.current = [];
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "video/mp4" });
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
      if (event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
      }
    };
    mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
      if (recordedChunksRef.current.length > 0 && !isUploading) {
        setIsUploading(true);
        const blob = new Blob(recordedChunksRef.current, { type: "video/mp4" });
        await uploadToCloudinary(blob);
        recordedChunksRef.current = [];
        mediaRecorder.start();
        setIsUploading(false);
      }
    };
    
    mediaRecorder.start();
    mediaRecorderRef.current = mediaRecorder;
    
    uploadIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (mediaRecorder.state === "recording" && !isUploading) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }
    }, 5000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let stream;

    const init = async () => {
      isComponentMounted.current = true; 
      stream = await startCamera();
      startRecording(stream);
    };

    init();

    return () => {
      isComponentMounted.current = false; 

      if (uploadIntervalRef.current) {
        clearInterval(uploadIntervalRef.current);
      }

      if (stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      }

      if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current.srcObject = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted className="w-full h-full object-cover" />;
};

export default WebCam;


problems I am facing

my upload functions get called two times , while uplaoding

enter image description here

also wanted two know since i am combining the videos at backend , is it possible to push videos in one order only , since some time one video chunks is still uploading and other video chunks gets upload

ps: if there any cheaper realtime recorder , you can suggest

Probably because of Strict Mode in react. Also, ensure that you are not generating multiple instances of MediaStream and triggering onstop callback for each instance.

It seems that your uploadToCloudinary function might be getting called more than once because the mediaRecorder.stop() call inside setInterval triggers the mediaRecorder.onstop event, which in turn starts a new recording and sets up another interval, potentially leading to overlapping calls.
1.Ensure Single Upload Trigger
Use a flag to ensure that the upload process is not started again if it's already in progress. You are already using isUploading, but let's refine its usage.
2.Manage Recording and Upload More Carefully
To avoid overlapping calls, ensure that the recording and uploading logic is managed properly and avoid restarting the recording immediately inside the onstop event handler if there's already an ongoing upload.
